# Applying cloud based map style with vue2-google-maps?

Tags: vue.js, google-maps-api-3, vue2-google-maps

As mentioned in these [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/cloud-based-map-styling#all), we can now apply cloud based styling to a map by setting the `mapId` property of the map.

I tried my luck with this:

```
<GmapMap ref="mapView" :center="driver.location" :zoom="15" :options="{ mapId: '84f11e866388cfc5' }">
</GmapMap>
```

But it didn't work. I also tried adding the map programatically with this:

```
new this.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('container'), {
     mapId: '84f11e866388cfc5',
     center: {lat:61.180059, lng: -149.822075},
     zoom:12
});
```

It does add the map, but doesn't apply the custom style designed in the cloud. According to the docs, it requires the `MAP_ID` to be set in the API URL as well like this:

```
<script
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&map_ids=MAP_ID&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

But how to do that? Is there a way to configure this plugin to set `MAP_ID` while importing the API? If not, is there any other Vue plugin which does the job?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i haven't played with that new feature, but that project has gone pretty stale, there is a new project that's gaining traction forked off of it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmap-vue

i made the switch and have had no issues, something worth looking at i'd say

Answer (score 1):

After looking trough the source code I found that you can add anything in the url when initializing the Gmap module

```
Vue.use(GmapVue, {
  load: {
    key: <your code>,
    libraries: "places",
    map_id: <your map-id>
  },
  installComponents: true
});
```

This successfully ads the map_id to the url, however it's still not working for me, even when using the correct url.

Maybe I did something wrong completely different and this "answer" actually works for you.

Comment: I tried something else to add the map_id to the url, but that's not enough. You need to initialise the map with this `map_id` to work. You can import the `google` object (refer to docs) and then use something like this for it apply the styles: : `            new this.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('container'), {
                mapId: 'YOUR_MAP_ID',
                center: {lat:LAT, lng: LNG},
                zoom:12
            });`

Answer (score 1):

```js
options : {
  mapId: "Your Map ID"
};
```

add map option, put it on your GmapMap tag

```html
 <GmapMap :options="options">
    </GmapMap>
```

Your main.js

```js
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: "Your map api key",
    map_ids: "Your map ID"
  }
});
```